# Physical meaning of RG transformation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, renormalization

When we do [RG transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization_group) in Statistical mechanics we eliminate unnecessary degrees of freedom and it leads us to the fixed point. How can I visualize it physically?

Comment: Maybe a better way of looking at it is that we are discovering a scale symmetry of the system, which looks similar to itself when we look at it on a larger (and potentially averaged) scale. This doesn't make the eliminated degrees of freedom superfluous in a physical sense, but it allows us to see their effective action in a new light.